# How do I use a list comprehension to generate more values in a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am currently trying to create a card came in Python 3.3 for a uk GCSE Computing assignment, and I want to know if I can use a list comprehension inside a list to create the face values for my cards.

My resulting list needs to  look like this:
`['Ace','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10','Jack','Queen','King']`

-

I have tried all the ways I can, to try get the code for this to work on one line.
Some of my attempts are as follows:

```
>>> ['Ace', [str(i) for i in range(2,11)] , 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
['Ace',['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],'Jack','Queen','King']
```

-

```
>>> ['Ace', (str(i) for i in range(2,11)), 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
['Ace', <generator object <genexpr> at 0x02BD1260>, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
```

-

The reason why I want to use the list comprehension is to get awarded a mark for coding knowledge. I know that I could just type the numbers into the list as I have done at the start of the question, but that one mark extra is a big deal for me.

I can get the list comprehension to work on if I assign it to a variable then use a `for` loop like below to insert the numbers into the `faces` list, but I *really, really, really* would prefer the code all on one line, as it will enable me to gain an extra mark for code efficiency too.

```
>>>faces = ['ace', 'jack', 'queen', 'king']
>>>numbers = [i for i in range(2,11)]
>>>for x in numbers:
...    faces.insert(x-1,x)
```

Comment: @JoshCaswell that is unnecessarily harsh.  The OP has clearly put in the effort to try and answer on his own, and as a teacher I would say any student willing to go the extra mile to type up this question and post it on SO easily earns the extra credit.

Comment: David K. has indeed apparently worked hard on this, @roippi, but it's still possible to ask for pointers or "what am I doing wrong", rather than just the final solution. It takes effort to do anything; in my book, you only get credit for putting effort towards the _right_ things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list concatenation:

```
>>> ['Ace'] + [str(i) for i in range(2,11)] + ['Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
```

Another option is to use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
>>> list(itertools.chain(['Ace'], [str(i) for i in range(2,11)],
                         ['Jack', 'Queen', 'King']))

['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
```

Comment: Really? As simple as that? I probably tried every piece of code going but this...

Comment: @DavidK. ... there is itertools.chain btw!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different way, using `dict.get`:

```
alternate_card_names = {1:'Ace',11:'Jack',12:'Queen',13:'King'}

[alternate_card_names.get(x,str(x)) for x in range(1,14)]
Out[19]: ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
```

Comment: This is a much better answer. You don;t have to deal with concatenating/joining multiple lists and its much cleaner to read